# Lock the SQLite database manually in Linux

Tags: linux, sqlite

I tried `begin exclusive` but I have no idea about how to lock the sqlite db manually. I am very new to the sqlite DB.

Comment: That is a really good question. I still have no idea, if there is a way to do it without a separate C program.

Comment: What is wrong with your `begin exclusive`?